# Operator precedence for integer division

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What will be the answer for x for the following
x = 27 * 24 \ 4 /2

is it 81 or 324 - considering that there is an integer division(/) which is said to have lower precedence than (/,*)

Your help in this regard will be much appreciated

Comment: what do you mean with '\'?

Comment: I would use parenthesis whenever I have such an expression, even if I know exactly which order is correct. To use parenthesis cannot be wrong, especially if you are asking for a programming language. This will help you or someone else read the expression later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpreting '\' as division:

Usually multiplication and division have the same precedence, just like addition and subtraction, and are thought as left associative. Hence your operation gives
$$
x = \left[(27*24)/4\right]/2 = 81
$$

---

If by '\' you mean "integer division", i.e. $a$ \ $b=\lfloor a/b\rfloor$, then probably it's precedence seems to depend on the programming language. In [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) $(//)$ has the same precedence as $(*)$ and $(/)$. On the other hand in [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_operator_precedence#Arithmetic_operators) $(/)$ is polymorphic (it's output depends on the type of the input values), while in [Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it seems to have a lower precedence, indeed. In that case you would get
$$
x= \left(27*24\right) \text{ \ } (4/2)=324
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated!

Comment: The "integer division" operator certainly exists in C/C++, it is written `7 / 5`. There is no "integer divided by integer gives real", you have to write for example `(double) 7 / 5`. Same precedence as `*`, associates to the left. Best bet, language independent: If you aren't 100% clear, use parentesis. Maybe you get it right, but it helps unconfuse whoever has to read your code later (probably youself in  a week or so ;-). Parentesis are cheap; finding mysterious bugs due to misreading expressions is long drawn out, embarrasing, and expensive.

Comment: @vonbrand Sure, what I was trying to say is that there is no different operator('/' is polymorphic), so which division operator you use depends on the type of the numbers you are dividing, and you cannot mix the two divisions without an explicit cast.

Comment: You can if your expression is `int / int / double`

Comment: @Hurkyl Didn't know that, thanks.